# which graphics card from the list is the best?

Tags: graphics-cards, pc

which graphics card from the list is the best for old games?
which graphic card is the most powerful?

```
                                                    |type|       memory  |pci          | standards             |memory clock      |gpu clock         |memory bus|
pegatron-radeon-hd-6450-1-gb-gddr3                  GDDR3        1GB     |PCI-e 2.1 x16|directx 11,   OpenG 4.1|1200MHz           |625MHz            64bit
gigabyte-gv-n210sl-1gi                              GDDR3        1GB     |PCI-e 3.0 x16|directx 10,   OpenG 3.1|1200MHz           |520MHz            64bit
asus-nvidia-geforce-1gbddr3                          DDR3        1GB     |PCI-e 3.0 x16|directx 11,   OpenG 3.3|600MHz            |589MHz            64bit 
hp-radeon-hd-8350-1gb-ddr3-64-bit                    DDR3        1GB     |PCI-e 2.0 x16|directx 11.2, OpenG 4.4|667MHz            |650MHz            64bit
```

Comment: The most powerful GPU today is an overclocked RX 6900XT, but for older games, thats OP. A GTX 950 will be ok, although those can be expensive (60 to 200 euros)

Comment: You need to specify what "old games" mean to you. People could interpret that as something as old as Commander Keen for DOS, DOOM, Half-Life 1, or even Skyrim. (*Which is 10 years old this year!*)

Comment: The third graphics card in that list might be impossible to identify, the model number isn't there.